# Condition of convergence in distribution of random variable.

Tags: probability, weak-convergence

I read on wiki and several books following statement:" A sequence of random variable $\{X_n\}$ converges in distribution to X if and only if limsup$\{Pr[X_n \in C ]\} \le Pr[ X \in C]$ for every closed subset $C \subset \mathbb{R}$. I found this statement is not trivial at all, and I got no ideal to deal with it.I need an instruction. thank so much

Comment: You probability started with an other definition of convergence in distribution. The ersult you mention is contained in portmanteau theorem, which indeed is non trivial.

Comment: Can you give me some reference about portmanteau theorem, i have found but they just state without solving. My main aim is proving:"  $X_n \xrightarrow^{d} c X \Rightarrow X_n \xrightarrow^{P} X$

Comment: You want to prove that convergence in distribution to a constant implies convergence in probability, don't you. Take a continuous bounded function with compact support, pieciwise linear, and which takes the value $1$ at $c$.